# how to inflate STVL's obstacles

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I'm using Spatio Temporal Voxel Layer in my ROS Navigation.I find that the obstacles STVL detected do not have inflation. I notice that obstacle layer's obstacle have inflation. I don't know where is the difference between obstacle layer and STVL in inflation and how to inflate STVL's obstacles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383326/how-to-inflate-stvl%27s-obstacles/) by [ZohyCao](https://answers.ros.org/users/78769/zohycao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same way you inflate the VL's cost grid. The inflation layer inflates all costs of all layers below it in the configuration. My guess is you added STVL at the end of your configuration and therefore after the inflation layer. Change the configuration to place the inflation layer at the end of the ***layered*** costmap again and that should solve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZohyCao](https://answers.ros.org/users/78769/zohycao/) on 2021-07-28**:
It works,thanks a lot!